# Best way to add data of multiple tables into mysql database from python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, windows, desktop-application

I am creating a windows GUI application using python and mysql. It is a student management system. I have written code to add `student` data into `students` table. What I would like to know is how to add data of `parent` and `classroom` tables from the code.

**Database tables**

```
students Table
ID, roll_no, name, gender, dob

parents Table
ID, student_id, first_name, last_name, address, email, contact_no

classrooms Table
ID, student_id, name
```

**python code**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pymysql

class Student:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Student Management System')
        self.root.geometry('1350x750+0+0')

        title = Label(self.root, text='Student Management System', bd=10, relief=GROOVE, font=('times new roman', 40, 'bold'), bg='yellow', fg='red')
        title.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        #Variables
        self.roll_no_var = StringVar()
        self.name_var = StringVar()
        self.gender_var = StringVar()
        self.dob_var = StringVar()

        #Frame to add data

        Data_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg='crimson')
        Data_Frame.place(x=20, y=100, width=450, height=580)

        m_title = Label(Data_Frame, text='Manage Students', font=('times new roman', 30, 'bold'), bg='crimson', fg='white')
        m_title.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)

        label_roll = Label(Data_Frame, text='Roll Number', font=('times new roman', 20, 'bold'), bg='crimson', fg='white')
        label_roll.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        text_roll = Entry(Data_Frame, textvariable=self.roll_no_var, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        text_roll.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        label_name = Label(Data_Frame, text='Name', font=('times new roman', 20, 'bold'), bg='crimson', fg='white')
        label_name.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        text_name = Entry(Data_Frame, textvariable=self.name_var, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        text_name.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        label_gender = Label(Data_Frame, text='Gender', font=('times new roman', 20, 'bold'), bg='crimson', fg='white')
        label_gender.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        dropdown_gender = ttk.Combobox(Data_Frame, textvariable=self.gender_var, font=('times new roman', 13, 'bold'), state='readonly')
        dropdown_gender['values'] = ('male', 'female', 'other')
        dropdown_gender.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)

        label_dob = Label(Data_Frame, text='dob', font=('times new roman', 20, 'bold'), bg='crimson', fg='white')
        label_dob.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        text_dob = Entry(Data_Frame, textvariable=self.dob_var, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        text_dob.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        #button frame
        button_Frame = Frame(Data_Frame, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg='crimson')
        button_Frame.place(x=15, y=515, width=420)

        add_btn = Button(button_Frame, text='Add', width=10, command=self.add_student).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        update_btn = Button(button_Frame, text='Update', width=10).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        delete_btn = Button(button_Frame, text='Delete', width=10).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        clear_btn = Button(button_Frame, command=self.clear_data, text='Clear', width=10).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

        #Display Frame
        Display_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg='crimson')
        Display_Frame.place(x=500, y=100, width=800, height=580)

        label_search = Label(Display_Frame, text='Search By', font=('times new roman', 20, 'bold'), bg='crimson', fg='white')
        label_search.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        dropdown_search = ttk.Combobox(Display_Frame, width=10, font=('times new roman', 13, 'bold'), state='readonly')
        dropdown_search['values'] = ('Roll', 'Name', 'Contact')
        dropdown_search.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)

        text_search = Entry(Display_Frame, font=('times new roman', 10, 'bold'), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        text_search.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='w')

        search_btn = Button(Display_Frame, text='Search', width=10).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
        show_btn = Button(Display_Frame, text='Show All', width=10).grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        #Table Frame
        Table_Frame = Frame(Display_Frame, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg='crimson')
        Table_Frame.place(x=10, y=70, width=750, height=500)

        scroll_x = Scrollbar(Table_Frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scroll_y = Scrollbar(Table_Frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.Student_Table = ttk.Treeview(Table_Frame, columns=('roll', 'name', 'gender', 'dob'), xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        scroll_x.config(command=self.Student_Table.xview)
        scroll_y.config(command=self.Student_Table.yview)
        self.Student_Table.heading('roll', text='Roll No')
        self.Student_Table.heading('name', text='Name')
        self.Student_Table.heading('gender', text='Gender')
        self.Student_Table.heading('dob', text='D O B')
        self.Student_Table['show'] = 'headings'
        self.Student_Table.column('roll', width=100)
        self.Student_Table.column('name', width=100)
        self.Student_Table.column('gender', width=100)
        self.Student_Table.column('dob', width=100)
        self.Student_Table.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.fetch_student_data()

    def add_student(self):
        con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='mastmacha123', database='student_management')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO students(roll_no, name, gender, dob) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (self.roll_no_var.get(), self.name_var.get(), self.gender_var.get(), self.dob_var.get()))
        con.commit()
        self.fetch_student_data()
        self.clear_data()
        con.close()

    def fetch_student_data(self):
        con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='student_management')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM students')
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        if len(rows) > 0:
            self.Student_Table.delete(*self.Student_Table.get_children())
            for row in rows:
                self.Student_Table.insert('', END, values=row)
            con.commit()
        con.close()

    def clear_data(self):
        self.roll_no_var.set('')
        self.name_var.set('')
        self.gender_var.set('')
        self.dob_var.set('')



root = Tk()
ob = Student(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here I would like to send data of `parent` and also `classroom`. The classrooms of students will be changed. It is `many to many` relationship. If I create new classes for `parent` and `classroom` how can I send the data of `parent` and `classroom` so that relationships of the models are maintained in the database?

Comment: i would model differently the classroom. i would create a tble classroom (id,name) and a table class_members (id_classroom,id_student)

Comment: Ok. What is the best way to send data of `parent` and `classroom` from the python code?

Comment: the best way i think is to do the job all around the classroom object. I mean : create class , insert it's student (which are to insert / select if they exist). And the parent could be inserted/updated while insert/update student object.